# How to write unit testcases for springboot schedulers which is using fixedDelay

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, scheduler, junit5

I have scheduled job using spring schedulers. Need help to write UnitTestcsaes for this.
On mocking and calling scheduler method how to handle this waiting time.. Do we really need to wait for such long time

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class RefreshDataScheduler {

@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${schedule.refresh.table.job.in.ms:1800000}")
    public void execute() {
    //fetch data from table A
    //inserts data to Table B using timestamps got from Table A
    //updates timestamp of Table A
    }
```

TEST:

```
public class RefreshTableSchedulerTest {

    
    @Mock
    ConfigRepository configRepository;
    
    @InjectMocks
    RefreshDataScheduler refreshDataScheduler;
    
    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testExecuteWithConfigData()  {
    A a = getConfigData();
        Mockito.when(configRepository.findById(REFRESH_TABLE)).thenReturn(Optional.of(a));
        refreshDataScheduler.execute(); 

    }
    
    private A getConfigData() {
        byte[] bytes = Utils.asBytes(UUID.randomUUID());
    A a = new A();
    a.setLastRefreshTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
    a.setRefreshTable(REFRESH_TABLE);
    return a;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: 1800 seconds is not feasible value for doing unit testing(i.e. waiting for execution to happen)  unless you want to try using it in local environment -- where you can verify if execution is happening at all

Comment: You don't need unit tests for Spring scheduling mechanism - it's been tested already by the Spring team. Move your scheduled logic to a separate service and test that.